# Getting an error in this Query

Tags: php, mysql

```
function saveFile($catId,$docuTitle,$linkTitle) {

 $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO categories (cd_title, cd_link)
                       VALUES ('$docuTitle','$linkTitle') WHERE c_name = '$catID'");    

            return 'yes';

        }
```

I want to insert the cd title and cd links based on the catergory selected.

Comment: What error? Can we get a database schema? Do your function parameters contain any single quotes?

Comment: oh please tell me that this is a test type thing and that you don't actually have sql executable directly from your webpage via that mysql_query() function

Comment: A 'WHERE' in an insert statement with no joins doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Use prepared statements or escape your variables with mysql_real_escape_string() if you can't.

Answer (score 2):

Edit:
Scott Saunders is right, you can't have a WHERE statement in an INSERT query.

Original answer:
You should give more info about the error, but you probably have a simple quote (') in on of the variables $docuTitle or $linkTitle, resulting in a malformed query.

You should escape these variables, as well as $catId, with mysql_real_escape_string() before using them in requests, or else your app will be vulnerable to SQL Injection.

You should read some docs about [PDO](http://php.net/PDO), it is a great tool to avoid this kind of mistakes in SQL queries, and it helps a lot for evolutivity and maintainability.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want:

```
INSERT INTO categories (cd_title, cd_link, c_name) VALUES ('$docuTitle','$linkTitle', '$catID')
```

Unless you're updating existing rows, then change 'INSERT INTO' to 'UPDATE'

Comment: jea INSERT and WHERE in the same statement makes no sense

Answer (score 1):

you are combining an INSERT statement and an UPDATE statement.

You need to choose the correct syntax:

```
INSERT INTO [TABLE] [COLUMNS] VALUES [VALUES]

UPDATE [TABLE] SET [COLUMNS] = [VALUE] WHERE [where clause]
```